# Insert a text transformation between open and json.load

Tags: python

I actually do the following code:

```
   with open(filename) as f:
       data = json.load(f)
```

I need to transform the content with some string replacements on the fly. So something like:

```
   def repair(???):
      # The function to write with at least a call of string or bytes replacement like content.replace("abc", "Def")
      return ????

   with open(filename) as f:
       data = json.load(repair(f))
```

How can I do that?

Comment: So the code you've provided doesn't work? `json.load(repair(f.read()))` should work. If not, please provide an example of the file content.

Comment: Yes it is just an example because I do not know how to write the repair function

Comment: Replace `???` with `something` (or some reasonable argument name) and it should work

Comment: Have you tried simply reading the file into the memory, replacing the content with regex and loading it as json? What exactly do you mean by `on the fly` ?

Comment: `json.load()` wants to read data from a file, or at least something *like* a file - your `repair()` function would have to provide its result in that form, perhaps an `io.StringIO` object.  This is certainly possible, but a lot more work than is really needed.  Far easier to read the file and return the modified version as an ordinary string - which can be passed directly to `json.loads()` (note the extra `s`).

Comment: If you have to use ```load``` for some reason, maybe you need ```fs```(PyFilesystem) lib to create a in-memory file to save the temp repaired result.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track. The JSON API provides a function to read a string of characters (`loads`) which you can use. To give you further pieces of information let's consider the following snippet:

```
   def repair(file_handle):
      repaired = file_handle.read()
      # there I assume the JSON payload just misses opening
      # and closing brackets, but you can do whatever you want
      repaired = "{{\n{}\n}}".format(repaired)
      return repaired # the repaired string of char 

   # as a good practice, always specify the required opening
   # permissions. Here we only want to read from the file.
   with open(filename, "r") as f:
       data = json.loads(repair(f))
```